# Using __setattr__ with dictionary inside class

Tags: python, python-3.x, setattr

I want to define a class like this:

```
class Test:
    _ID = itertools.count()

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = next(self._ID)
        self.__setattr__('_dict', {})


    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self._dict[key]


    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self._dict[key] = value
```

What is the best approach in this case?

Comment: What is this line supposed to do `self.__setattr__('_dict', {})`?

Comment: @mapf i used it to define dictionary  inside the class to prevent from recursion with __setattr__.

Comment: @JanKoval But you're calling `self.__setattr__` explicitly; that's driving straight at the problem you're trying to avoid. On the other hand, if you called the `__setattr__` in the `object` class instead, you would avoid the overridden method that causes the recursion.

Comment: @khelwood so, what i need to change, to use something like this:
test_object.a = 5 (a is the new key in dictionary)

Comment: @JanKoval Hopefully the answer posted answers that.

Comment: Python objects already have an optimised ``__dict__``. Why do you want to manually recreate this?

Answer (score 1):

`self.id =` calls `__setattr__` for `id` key. Inside `__setattr__` you try to get `self._dict` which triggers `__getattr__` since the key `_dict` is not yet defined and inside `__getattr__` you try to do the same thing - get `self._dict`, so the `__getattr__` is called again, and again... up to recursion limit.

Use `super()` to call the default `__setattr_` method, so your `__getattr__` implementation won't be to get `self._dict`:

```
class Test:
    _ID = itertools.count()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__setattr__("id", next(self._ID))
        super().__setattr__("_dict", {})

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self._dict[key]

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self._dict[key] = value
```